# Truncate not working with google-drive in command line

Tags: linux, bash, google-drive-api, truncate, rclone

I am using `rclone` to work with **Google Drive on the command line**.
I want to create a file of a **specific size** using `truncate`, but I get the error

```
$ truncate -s 4096 qwe
truncate: failed to truncate 'qwe' at 4096 bytes: Operation not permited
```

I understand that there are not enough permissions, but I don't know how to get them or how to get around it :(

Help me pls

**UPD1:**

I work remotely with a google disk, it is mounted to my server using `rclone`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj02j.jpg)

**UPD2:**

Everything works fine when I do it locally

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDkY2.jpg)

Comment: Well, did you try to change the permissions (`chmod u+w qwe`)? Are you the file owner (what do you see if you type `ls -l qwe`)?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I am tried it, the permissions were the same. 
I work remotely with a google disk, it is mounted to my server using rclone. Updated the question

Comment: Try: `dd if=/dev/zero of=qwe bs=1M count=4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to get around it :(

Instead of `truncate`, which calls `ftruncate`, really create the file with all zeros.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=qwe bs=1M count=4
```